# Use Anaconda with multiple environment in a single script

Tags: python, anaconda

Let's say I have a script with two projects, each of them have its anaconda environment and its packages. For example the packages needed from project 1 are in env1 and the packages needed from project2 are in env2.
Of course when I need to run project1 I do source activate env1 and viceversa for project2.
Now, in my Python script, being in env1 I need to run project2, like this:

```
source activate env1
python project1.py
```

project1.py:

```
import libraries_for_project1
from file_for_project2 import ClassProject2

#project1 stuff
ClassProject2.somemethod() #project2 stuff
#project1 stuff
```

What I wanna do is to change (or activate above) the env2 inside the python script itself.
I tried:

```
import libraries_for_project1
from file_for_project2 import ClassProject2
import os
import subprocess 

#project1 stuff

subprocess.run("bash -c 'source activate ~/anaconda3/envs/env2'", shell=True)
print(os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV']) #this return env1
ClassProject2.somemethod() #this cause errors because of some packages are not installed in env1
subprocess.run("bash -c 'source deactivate'", shell=True)
print(os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV'])

#project1 stuff
```

Do you have any suggestion? (Of course I cannot install libraries of env2 in env1)

Answer (score 0):

Modularize and create a separate file/folder for the project2. The thing is when you are working in one environment and want to start executing some part of the code using another environment is impossible as the execution starts from the beginning.

Example:

```
import pandas
pandas.import_csv('something.csv')
# Start using the second environment
## Code to be executed using another environment
## Write this code as a separate file
## Write code to execute that file using environment 2
# After Completion of execution
# Continue your code which doesn't require environment 2
```